# MongoDB find objects sorted by string dateTime

Tags: mongodb, sorting, datetime, collections

I have a mongoDB with companies having the following structure:

```
"name": "CORESITE",
"isin": "us21870q1058",
"XDateInserted": "2020-09-16 14:19",
"XDateUpdated": "2020-10-09 14:38",
```

i wish to query all companies to an array, sorted by XdateUpdated. The following bit of code succeeds in sorting the result by name, however, sorting by XdateUpdated just return me a random order. Any Solutions ?

```
    const allCompanies = await database
    .get()
    .db(Mongo.db)
    .collection(Mongo.CC)
    .find(
        {
            circulate: { $ne: false },
        },
        {
            projection: {
                _id: 0,
                isin: 1,
                name: 1,
                XDateInserted: 1,
            },
        }
    )
    .sort({ name: -1 })
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using aggregation.
You'll first have to convert the string date to Date type. Then Sort it.

```
const allCompanies = await database
.get()
.db(Mongo.db)
.collection(Mongo.CC)
.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            updatedDateFormatted: {
                $dateFromString: {
                    dateString: "$XDateUpdated"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            updatedDateFormatted: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            updatedDateFormatted: 0 // To hide the custom field from result
        }
    }
])
.toArray();
```